# How can I delete the keyboard buffer in assembly?

Tags: assembly, keyboard, buffer, x86-16

I have this code that prints "hi" when I press 'h' on the keyboard, but when I press it non-stop for a few seconds, It still prints "hi" in a delay. I'm pretty sure it happens because when I press on 'h', it "spam" the keyboard buffer and I think I need to reset or delete the keyboard buffer every time I'm entering the proc "key" to make it work. is there any interrupt I can use for this? Here's the code:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h


DATASEG

timeEnter dw ?
mil db ?
count db ?
hi dw ? 
message db 'hi',10,13,'$'


CODESEG


proc delaytime
push bp
mov bp, sp

push ax
push bx
push cx
push si
push dx
push di

    mov bl, [bp+4] ;offset time enter
    mov [mil],0
    mov [count],0

    mov ah, 2Ch
    int 21h
    mov [mil], dl
    jmp L1
L2:
    inc [count]
    mov [mil], dl
L1:
    mov ah, 2Ch
    int 21h
    cmp dl, [mil]
    je L1
    cmp [count],bl
    jne L2


pop di
pop dx
pop si 
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
pop bp
ret 2
endp delaytime

proc key
push bp
mov bp,sp
push ax
push bx
push cx
push si
push dx
push di



    mov [hi],0
    mov ah, 01
    int 16h
    
    jz L3
    
    mov ah, 00h
    int 16h ;al=ascii charachter
    
    cmp al, 68h
    jne L3
    mov [hi],1
    
    
    
    
    
L3:



pop di
pop dx
pop si 
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax
pop bp
ret 
endp key

















start :
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
L:
    ; Graphic mode
    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h
    
    call key
    cmp [hi],1
    jne L4
    
    ;print
    mov dl, 15   ;J
    mov dh, 2    ;I
    mov bh, 0     ;Display page 0
    mov ah, 02h   ;SetCursor
    int 10h
    mov dx, offset message
    mov ah, 09h   ;DispayString
    int 21h 



L4: 

    mov [timeEnter],3
    push [timeEnter]
    call delaytime


    
    ;text mode 
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 2
    int 10h

    jmp L
    
exit :
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
END start
```

Comment: If you don't want to receive repeated keypresses while the user presses and holds a key I'm afraid you will have to hook and monitor interrupt 09h (IRQ #1) calls and read the keyboard port to find out when a key is pressed down ("make" scancode) and released ("break" scancode). You can empty the buffer used by the interrupt 16h services at any given time by checking with function 01h if any keypress is queued, and if so consume it with function 00h then loop. But if the user keeps holding the key you will almost immediately receive subsequent keypresses again.

Comment: Hmm, draining the queue may actually work for you just fine I think upon rereading your question. You can show your message, run your delay, then drain the queue. If the user still holds the key you will receive it again and enter another delay.