# how can I empty the keyboard buffer in assembly?

Tags: assembly, keyboard, buffer, x86-16, emu8086

I need to clean the keyboard buffer and I don't know the interrupt for that. I know you need to promote the keyboard head pointer by 2, but I don't know how.

Comment: Look at [INT 16h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-16.htm) and [Keyboard buffer start/stop address](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/93-rom_bios_variables.html).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by emptying the keyboard buffer?

Comment: It's a little complicated, I'm trying to build a Tetris game in assembly and everything works fine. I take a cube, print it on the screen(in a delay time so it won't be so fast), delete it, and print it one line under, so it's in a loop (until it hits another cube/floor), and at the beginning of this loop I check for the keyboard input-a=left, d=right. if any of them are pressed I move the cubes. but if I press non-stop It continues to move because the printing is slower than the computer, so I thought that maybe clearing the buffer after every keyboard check would help. hope it's understood

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of your earlier question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620607/how-can-i-delete-the-keyboard-buffer-in-assembly where I commented on how to use interrupt 16h services 01h and 00h in a loop to drain the keypress queue.

Answer (score 2):

When the BIOS.ReadKeyboardStatus function 01h returns, a set zero flag indicates that no key is waiting aka the keyboard buffer maintained by BIOS is empty. If the zero flag is not set, then one or more keys are waiting in the buffer. Just remove these one at a time with the BIOS.ReadKeyboardCharacter function 00h.
Your basic code to empty the keyboard buffer therefore is:

```
EmptyKeyboardBuffer:
  push ax
.more:
  mov  ah, 01h        ; BIOS.ReadKeyboardStatus
  int  16h            ; -> AX ZF
  jz   .done          ; No key waiting aka buffer is empty
  mov  ah, 00h        ; BIOS.ReadKeyboardCharacter
  int  16h            ; -> AX
  jmp  .more          ; Go see if more keys are waiting
.done:
  pop  ax
  ret
```

For the problem you seem to have with your Tetris game and as a refinement, you could choose to not just empty the keyboard buffer whole, but only remove the repetitions of the current key. This way you avoid the issue of unwanted repeats but still allow for quick detection of changes in direction. 'quick detection' here means that the key for the opposite direction arrives while still drawing the picture for the current key.
The BIOS.ReadKeyboardStatus function 01h conveniently provides in the AX register a preview for the first key that is available in the keyboard buffer, provided a key is waiting of course. AL will contain its ASCII code and AH will contain its scancode.

```
AvoidSameKeyRepeats:
  push ax
.more:
  mov  ah, 01h        ; BIOS.ReadKeyboardStatus
  int  16h            ; -> AX ZF
  jz   .done          ; No key waiting aka buffer is empty
  cmp  al, CurrentKey ; ASCII code (ignoring scancode)
  jne  .done
  ; Only remove if it's the same key ("a" = left, "d" = right)
  mov  ah, 00h        ; BIOS.ReadKeyboardCharacter
  int  16h            ; -> AX
  jmp  .more          ; Go see if more keys are waiting
.done:
  pop  ax
  ret
```

Assuming you fetch a key with:

```
; IN () OUT (al) MOD (ah)
GetKeyboardKey:
  mov  ah, 00h        ; BIOS.ReadKeyboardCharacter
  int  16h            ; -> AX
  mov  CurrentKey, al ; ASCII code (ignoring scancode)
  ret
```